# Big FontSize produces empty result

Tags: graphics, style, text, fonts

```
Style[A, FontSize -> 540]
(* A with FontSize 540*)

Style[A, FontSize -> 541]
(* Nothing*)
```

[image]

I think FontSize 541 is not too big. Practically there may be a person who want it.
I don't think it's going to be a burden on the CPU or RAM to make the text just a little bigger than fontsize 540.
Also, it is not reasonable to produce wrong, empty result without any message.

In my short experience, this error seems to occur when the text size exceeds a certain number of pixels.
And the condition just mentioned looks necessary and sufficient condition.
Saying again, regardless of the **method of *setting* size** of text in `Graphihcs`(there are many size related functions Fontsize.. Imagesize.. Magnificatin.. Scaled..), as soon as the number of pixels occupying the text exceeds certain numbers, the error(=disappearing of the Text) occurs.
It also happens while resizing by clicking on the frame of the `Graphics`.

Question :)

Is there a case where this error occurs even for small pixels? It will be more fatal.

Is there a way to make larger text, like `A` with FontSize 541 ?

Comment: Can't see this on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. Please include the output of `$Version` to the post.

Comment: `$Version` is "13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (August 14, 2022)". Hope you test with somewhat larger FontSize. I apply `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, GraphicsBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 72/120}]`, and I use windows 10 and set text size 125%.

Comment: That is indeed ... weird. It happens for me both in 12.3 and 13.0 (Windows), although the threshold is at slightly larger font size (676). I can still "select" the letter, but nothing the letter itself is not visible. It appears if I choose a smaller magnification (bottom-right corner). I think this peculiarity is worth being reported to [Wolfram Technical Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback).

Comment: Thank you for the interests!